# How to make symmetrical images scroll over each other?

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, scroll, parallax

It's quite hard to explain, so check out http://www.adhamdannaway.com.

I would like to create a similar front-end to my online portfolio, but I can't find any information as to how I would go with it. would it be `jquery` or `css`?

A similar system is shown here: http://www.indigorenderer.com/sketchup/

When viewing the code, the html sizes change as you move over the image.
I think it has something to do with parallax scrolling.

Could someone please shed some light on the situation please and point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: That is pretty sweet :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, The second link has two images, one is black and white, other is colored. And then using css position place both images one above the other(display one image for now).Then using jquery you can do onhover event on the image - change the width of the other image and do display block only and increase width as the hover .

Answer (score 0):

The effect is [parallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/). This [example](http://stephband.info/jparallax/demos/target.html) shows the effect you probably want. Notice how the red layer follows the cursor and the background image stays in place. You will want to set the background as one image and the "red" layer as a second image. You will also want to set the "red" layer to only move in the x-direction.